# Django forms ForeignKey groups

Tags: python, django, django-forms, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I'm designing a Django application for athletes to register for a competition. There are several weight classes available to each athlete and each weight class is stored in a foreign key in another model. The models are as follows:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    tourney_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tourney_date = models.DateTimeField()
    tourney_classes = models.ManyToManyField(WeightClass, related_name='tourney_name', blank=True)

class Athlete(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email_address = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    athlete_class = models.ForeignKey(WeightClass, related_name='entries')

class WeightClass(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    class_info = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class_group = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The weight classes are separated into groups and I want the classes to be grouped on the registration form. For example we have Junior Men as a group. Within the Junior Men's group we have Lightweight, Middleweight, and Heavyweight. Then we have Junior Women, Senior Men, etc. I want the form to be option buttons for each weight class grouped separately.

- Junior Men

  - Lightweight
  - Middleweight
  - Heavyweight
- Junior Women

  - Lightweight
  - Middleweight
  - Heavyweight
- etc.

So I need my form to query the database for a tournament, and then retrieve all of the weight classes for that particular tournament, and then display the weight classes as shown above. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you have `class_group` as a ForeignKey relationship within `WeightClass`. Hence something like:

```
class WeightClass(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    class_info = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class_group = models.ForeignKey(WeightGroup)

class WeightGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

You could then first display all weight groups, and then filter `WeightClass` based on the user selection.

If the *Lightweight* instance should be the same for both *Junior Men* and *Junior Women* then you should maybe consider to model it as a many to many relationship.